# How to set up Firebase location as a Backbone Model ID?

Tags: backbone.js, firebase, backfire

I use BackFire - Firebase integration with Backbone.js

Examining [BackFire demo](http://firebase.github.io/backfire/) application I see that Firebase location is set as "root" key and as a value for ID key.

```
JSON response from Firebase

 {
  "-It-MYaWEFBI1QGD8PXB": 
    {
     "title":dummy title",
     "id": "-It-MYaWEFBI1QGD8PXB"
    }
 }
```

In Model I see that Firebase location is set as Model ID.

```
Backbone Model attributes 

attributes: {
  id: '-IswDV_2rwZu3WHO0giQ'
  title: 'dummy title'
},
id : '-IswDV_2rwZu3WHO0giQ'
```

I wonder how does data structure look like in Firebase Forge (backend) which creates response described above?

Answer (score 1):

By going to the TODO page and typing in this command:

```
new Firebase('https://backbone.firebaseio.com').once('value', function(ss) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(ss.val(), null, 2))});
```

I am able to see the data structure looks like this:

```
{
  "-It-MYaWEFBI1QGD8PXB": {
    "id": "-It-MYaWEFBI1QGD8PXB",
    "title": "prepare lunch"
  },
  "-It-Mch8_bA23vkwAbUZ": {
    "id": "-It-Mch8_bA23vkwAbUZ",
    "title": "install Linux"
  }
}
```

So basically, because it's a demo, Anant has obeyed KISS and put the todo items at the root level. In a sophisticated application, you'd need to have more nesting and depth, of course.